# Getting the download url of a video from a site

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to build a web scraper which downloads videos from "fmovies.se".

I was not able to fully extract the video url given the webpage.

The webpage I'm considering is "https://fmovies.se/film/la-cage-doree.5283j".

Two queries are required to retrieve the video url.

The initial one is 'https://fmovies.se/ajax/episode/info?ts=1483027200&=2399&id=9076jn&update=0'.

The query is composed of "ts", "_", "id" and "update" elements. Everything except "_" part was mentioned in html code of the webpage.

I couldn't get from where "_2399" part was coming.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Elaborate your problem some more and share the snippet to see what's the problem is...

Comment: @DinuDuke updated the question

Comment: still i am not able to get you... show me some code snippet...

Answer (score 2):

Even if you figure out how those parameters are computed, they can change their algorithm at any moment, which this site specifically has done in the past, see this [thread](https://github.com/coder-alpha/FMoviesPlus.bundle/issues/11).

You need a long lasting solution — a headless browser.

You can use a headless browser to simulate user interactions programmatically and intercept the XHR request that you are looking for (e.g. `https://fmovies.se/ajax/episode/info?ts=1483027200&=2399&id=9076jn&update=0`).

One of the best headless browsers out there is [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and there's a lot of information on how to use it.